# How to add more items in ListItemText react

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code here that will make a list of reviews in react, is there a way to add more text into ListItemText because most online tutorials only go up to secondary but I want to add a tertiary text if possible

```
                    <Paper>
                        <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
                            {this.state.bookReviews.map((review =>
                                <>
                                    <ListItem alignItems="flex-start" key={review.id}>
                                    <ListItemAvatar>
                                        <Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" />
                                    </ListItemAvatar>
                                    <ListItemText
                                        primary={review.heading}
                                        secondary={
                                            <React.Fragment>
                                                <Typography
                                                    sx={{ display: 'inline' }}
                                                    component="span"
                                                    variant="body2"
                                                    color="text.primary"
                                                >

                                                </Typography>
                                                {review.reviewText}
                                            </React.Fragment>
                                        }
                                    />
                                </ListItem>
                                    <Divider variant="inset" component="li"/>
                                </>

                            ))}
                        </List>
                    </Paper>
```

Comment: I assume this is MUI?  [I don't see a `tertiary` property](https://mui.com/api/list-item-text/).  Perhaps what you're looking to do is style the markup in your `secondary` property then?

Comment: oh okay, i thought that they had a tertiary property. I'll markup the secondary property.